# Gtk Window with two side panels

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject, gtkmm3

I am trying to implement a window with two resize-able side panels and an area in between in GTK3. Examples of what I am trying to achieve are RawTherapee and Glade.

Placing two GtkPaned in a GtkWindow does not work.

Any pointer/tip on how to achieve such a layout are highly welcome! It does not matter if the code is in C, C++ or Python, as long as I can see the concept.

Comment: Could you elaborate why two GtkPaned's don't work? Did you nest them one within the other? How do you expect resizing to work? Is the movement of one slider meant to be able to push that of the other?

Comment: I placed them next to each other instead of nesting them within each other. GTK newbie error... Now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Education isn't an error.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a minimal example how I solved it.

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


window = Gtk.Window(title="Two side panels")
box = Gtk.VBox()
paned1 = Gtk.Paned()
paned2 = Gtk.Paned()
button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Button1")
button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Button2")
button3 = Gtk.Button(label="Button3")
paned1.add1(button1)
paned1.add2(paned2)
paned2.add1(button2)
paned2.add2(button3)
box.pack_start(paned1, True, True, 0)
box.pack_start(paned2, True, True, 0)

window.add(box)
window.show_all()
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned Glade. Looking at the source code (https://github.com/GNOME/glade/blob/master/src/glade.glade) it would appear that they do use two nested GtkPaned's

Comment: I was actually looking at glade's source code and also RawTherapee's. The structure was not easily recognizable. I learned about GTK-Inspector which allows to investigate the object hierarchy of an application. To start: GTK_DEBUG=interactive your-application. It revealed nested GtkPaneds.

Comment: Glade programs itself in glade. It uses xml. You can see the nesting more clearly, but not too useful for anyone who hasn't had reason to delve into it.